# Conditional Voltage output

Tags: switches, comparator

I apologize if this is extremely simple, but I am trying to design this:

I input 2 voltages, one is 12 V and the other is on the order of .5V.  I want to know if there is something I can set up that will output 12 V if the reading of the smaller voltage is larger than a certain value.

i.e

If small voltage > v_crit ; out=12V

If small voltage < v_crit ; out = 0.

My thoughts are to do a switch controlled by a microcontroller, but I am wondering if there is an easier/cheaper way.

Comment: You mean like a comparator?

Comment: Well the 12V will always be larger than the smaller voltage

Comment: I am interlocking the two signals

Comment: You mean like a comparator *with a fixed voltage reference* (v_crit)?

Comment: Something like this would work: http://www.linear.com/product/LT6703  You need to decide if you want the output to be able to supply any current; if so, you'll also need a relay or transistor after the comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If speed of response is no great concern and only moderate accuracy is required, something like this would work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR6jxM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a practical circuit you may wish to sink current rather than just source it to RL, low pass filtering may be required, you may wish to restrict the setting range of R5 with a few resistors (say 0.4 to 0.6V nominal), and you may need or want to add some hysteresis. Also a bypass cap on the power supply and more if it's an automotive 12V.